# BizTalk - Build XSD for flat file with words delimiter at start and end of records

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, flat-file, biztalk-2013

I am trying to build an XSD file based on the following text file (flat file). I am using the flat file schema wizard but can't achieve what I want.

```
:BEGIN
Key1 Value1
Key2 Value2
:END
:BEGIN
Key1 Value1
Key2 Value2
Key3 Value3
:END
:BEGIN
:END
```

The XSD would be something like :

```
Record (Delimited by :BEGIN and :END)
|_Association (Delimited by \n)
  |_Key (Delimited by space, first occurence)
  |_Value (second occurence)
```

I would like my txt file to be transformed as an instance of the xsd file in xml. The result would be something like :

```
<Record>
  <Association>
    <Key>Key1</Key>
    <Value>Value1</Value>
  </Association>
  <Association>
    <Key>Key2</Key>
    <Value>Value2</Value>
  </Association>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Association>
    <Key>Key1</Key>
    <Value>Value1</Value>
  </Association>
  <Association>
    <Key>Key2</Key>
    <Value>Value2</Value>
  </Association>
  <Association>
    <Key>Key3</Key>
    <Value>Value3</Value>
  </Association>
</Record>
```

There is only 2 records because last :BEGIN:END block is empty.

My main issue is that I can't find out how to delimit my records by :START and :END tags. Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do, but not with the Wizard.  It is a matter of manually building it up and testing the structure as you add definitions.

It is a matter of using Tag Identifiers for the :BEGIN and :END as well using a Sequence Group to say that these re-occur.

Additionally at the `<Schema>` level set Parser Optimization to Complexity.

Depending on what defines the end of your line, you may need to adjust the 0x0A 0x0D (Carriage Return & Line Feed) to what your file actually contains.  Also if the last line does not finish with a CR/LF then change it from being Postfix (after) to Infix (between).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO63600733" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO63600733" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Root" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="complexity" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Record">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" sequence_number="1" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:groupInfo sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="BEGIN">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" tag_name=":BEGIN" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:complexType />
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Accociation">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_delimiter_type="char" child_order="infix" child_delimiter=" " sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:element name="Key" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                          <xs:appinfo>
                            <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                          </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                      </xs:element>
                      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                          <xs:appinfo>
                            <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="2" justification="left" />
                          </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="END">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name=":END" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0A 0x0D" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:complexType />
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

With your example input gives

```
<Root xmlns="http://Scratch.SO63600733">
    <Record xmlns="">
        <BEGIN/>
        <Accociation>
            <Key>Key1</Key>
            <value>Value1</value>
        </Accociation>
        <Accociation>
            <Key>Key2</Key>
            <value>Value2</value>
        </Accociation>
        <END/>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <BEGIN/>
        <Accociation>
            <Key>Key1</Key>
            <value>Value1</value>
        </Accociation>
        <Accociation>
            <Key>Key2</Key>
            <value>Value2</value>
        </Accociation>
        <Accociation>
            <Key>Key3</Key>
            <value>Value3</value>
        </Accociation>
        <END/>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <BEGIN/>
        <END/>
    </Record>
</Root>
```

Comment: Wow, this is incredible, you are amazing, thank you very much !! This is working very well.

Comment: Hi there, I now encounter another issue, when i use your xsd here and "validate instance" functionnality with my txt file, it works great. Now when i deploy my project with a custom receive pipeline with flat file disassembler, it throws an error for the same txt file "The remaining stream has unrecognizable data", any idea ?

Comment: @Gosfly Ok, made two minor tweaks 1) removed Min Occurs from the END tag, which then causes it to fail in Visual Studio (as the last end was not appearing in the output).   2) At the `<Schema>` definition changed Parser Optimization to Complexity.  Give that a go.

Comment: After applying these two minor tweaks, validate instance now fails in VS as well as flat file disassembler in pipeline with Unexpected end of stream while looking for:'\r\n'

Comment: Actually, these two minor tweaks work great when my txt file ends with a new line after ":END" row. If the last line is ":END" and not a new empty line, it fails.

Comment: @Gosfly If you don't have a  carriage return & new line at the end, then change it from being Postfix to Infix for the CR LF (0x0A 0x0D0) delimiter.  Also if you only have one or the other, change it to match your file